# SQL SELECT Permission for Object to Object

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, permissions

I have a specific user for running some SQL from a windows service.
The specific user when accessing a view can see it perfectly fine.
The stored procedure that is calling that view (WHEN EXECUTED) is throwing an error:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object...

I am used to setting permissions this way:

```
USE DatabaseName;   
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::ObjectName  
    TO UserName;
```

I could not find anything that tells me how to set permissions for an Object to another object. I could only set permissions for a user to be able to EXEC or SELECT from an OBJECT.

Comment: Does the account the windows service connects via have the correct permissions on both the view *and* the stored procedure?

Comment: Actually I would be able to use my own account to execute the permissions. Just wanted to know how to write it from an object to an object

Comment: I am not referring to granting the permissions, I am saying that you need to make sure the user that is making the request has the necessary permissions on both the stored procedure *and* the view.

Comment: @iamdave The issue is that I have permission to EXECUTE the stored precedure but I dont have permissions to see a specific view. I just wanted the correct format to issue the permissions in a script.

Comment: Why are you so stuck on the concept of providing permissions to a procedure?  Either provide the user permissions on the view as well as the procedure or use the `execute as` command within your procedure.

Comment: @iamdave thats a good point. The user did not have SELECT Permissions on the View.